# DateTimePicker Range for VB.net and Access Database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am a frustrated Newb. I am trying to use a couple of datetimepickers to display the date range from an Access Database in a DataGridView. Here is the code I am using:

```
Dim dtp1 As String = DateTimePicker1.Text
Dim dtp2 As String = DateTimePicker2.Text
Dim strCriteria, task As String

Me.Refresh()
If dtp1 = "" Then
MsgBox("Please Enter The Date Range", vbInformation, "Date Range Required")
Else
strCriteria = "([Appt Date] >= #" & dtp1 & "# And [Appt Date] <= #" & dtp2 _
& "#)"
task = "SELECT * FROM BDC1 WHERE (" & strCriteria & ") order by [Appt Date]"

End If
```

Comment: and, what is problem? describe problem... try using `between`, for example `where [App Date] between #date1# and #date2#` instead >= and <=. and, take care about date format... I mostly use `yyyy-mm-dd`... and, again, you don't need those ) in sql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your code to :

```
      Dim dtp1 As String = DateTimePicker1.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("#yyyy/MM/dd#")
      Dim dtp2 As String = DateTimePicker1.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("#yyyy/MM/dd#")

       Dim con As SqlConnection ="Your connection string here"       
       task = "SELECT * FROM BDC1 WHERE [Appt Date] BETWEEN '" + dtp1 + "' AND '" + dtp2 + "'
       order by [Appt Date]"
       Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(task , con)
       dim dt as new datatable()
       da.Fill(dt)
       con.Close()
       YourdatagridviewName.Datasource=dt
```

Comment: So I am using it but what is the best way to update the datagridview to show it? @ Beldi Anouar

Comment: @Ken I have changed my answer to show you how to update your datagridView with affecting your result of your query as datasource to it .If my answer is helful to you please mark it

Comment: I would be happy to mark it helpful but so far it still does not work.

Comment: I will be happy to mark it as good and answered, when I still cannot get it to work. This is really frustrating me. Thanks for your help so far. @Beidi Anouar

Comment: Line #4 is an error:   Task is a Class type and cannot be used as an Expression @Beidi Anouar

Comment: Dim dtp1 As String = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("#MM/dd/yyyy#")
        Dim dtp2 As String = DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("#MM/dd/yyyy#")

        Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\BDC3.mdb")
        Task = "SELECT * FROM BDC1 WHERE [Appt Date] BETWEEN '" + dtp1 + "' AND '" + dtp2 + "'
       order by [Appt Date]"
        Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(Task, con)
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        da.Fill(dt)
        con.Close()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt  @Beidi Anouar

Comment: you can replace Task by an other variable :        Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM BDC1 WHERE [Appt Date] BETWEEN '" + dtp1 + "' AND '" + dtp2 + "' order by [Appt Date]"
        Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, con)

Comment: My code now looks like this: Dim dtp1 As String = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("#MM/dd/yyyy#")
Dim dtp2 As String =DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("#MM/dd/yyyy#")
Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\BDC3.mdb")
        Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM BDC1 WHERE [Appt Date] BETWEEN '" + dtp1 + "' AND '" + dtp2 + "' order by [Appt Date]"
        Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        Dim dt As New DataTable()      da.Fill(dt)     con.Close()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt @Beidi Anouar

Comment: Here is the error that I am gettting:  An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Data type mismatch in criteria expression. @Beidi Anouar